# Upgrade error in Pfsense

Tags: freebsd, pfsense

I am experiencing an error while trying to upgrade Pfsense 2.3.2 to 2.3.3_1.

> [2.3.2-RELEASE] pfSense-upgrade -d
>
> Updating repositories metadata...
>
> Updating pfSense-core repository catalogue...
>
> pfSense-core repository is up-to-date.
>
> Updating pfSense repository catalogue...
>
> pfSense repository is up-to-date.
>
> All repositories are up-to-date.
>
> Upgrading pkg...
>
> Updating pfSense-core repository catalogue...
>
> pfSense-core repository is up-to-date.
>
> Updating pfSense repository catalogue...
>
> pfSense repository is up-to-date.
>
> All repositories are up-to-date.
>
> New version of pkg detected; it needs to be installed first.
>
> Checking integrity... done (0 conflicting)
>
> The following 1 package(s) will be affected (of 0 checked):
>
> Installed packages to be UPGRADED:
>           pkg: 1.8.7_1 -> 1.9.4_1 [pfSense]
>
> Number of packages to be upgraded: 1 [1/1] Upgrading pkg from 1.8.7_1
>   to 1.9.4_1...
>
> pkg: sqlite error while executing INSERT OR REPLACE INTO packages(
>   origin, name, version, comment, desc, message, arch, maintainer, www,
>   prefix, flatsize, automatic, licenselogic, mtree_id, time,
>   manifestdigest, dep_formula, vital)VALUES( ?1, ?2, ?3, ?4, ?5, ?6, ?7,
>   ?8, ?9, ?10, ?11, ?12, ?13, (SELECT id FROM mtree WHERE content =
>   ?14), NOW(), ?15, ?16, ?17 ) in file pkgdb.c:1651: database disk image
>   is malformed

Anyone knows how to resolve this issue without lost the pfsense config?
I would appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Comment: Why not just pull a config backup, do a clean install, and then restore the config?

Comment: hi, thanks, this could be a work arround for sure, but im looking for a more accurate solution to this specific issue.